# v-for loop is not displaying any data rather it is just repeating table rows

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, axios

this v-for loop is just repeating the table rows so many times without displaying any data.

```
 <table class="table">
 <thead>
 <th>Id</th>
 <th>Name</th>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 <tr v-for="t in tasks ">
 <td>{{ t.id }}</td>
 <td>{{ t.name }}</td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

here's my controller function from where I am trying to return the json data

```
public function index()
{
    $tasks = Todo::all();
    return request()->json($tasks, 200);
}
```

here's the script, and it shows no error on console

```
<script>
export default {
  data(){
    return{
      tasks:{},
    }
  },
  methods:{
  },
  created(){
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/#/example/tasks')
    .then((response) => this.tasks = response.data )
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
    console.log("Tasks Component Mounted.....");
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: What does `this.tasks` look like when you log it out in the `.then(..)` function?

Comment: Can you check the network tab on your browser's developer mode? Is the GET request getting sent out and the expected JSON returned?

Comment: Install the [Vue DevTools Browser Extension](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools)  it will allow you to inspect your component at runtime and makes it significantly easier to debug.

Comment: it seems like `t.id` and `t.name` is null, so it will see empty table cells. try this `<tr v-for="t in tasks "><td>{{ JSON.stringify(t) }}</td>
 <td>{{ t.id }}</td>
 <td>{{ t.name }}</td>
 </tr>`, what is rendered out at first column?

Comment: when I log it as `.then((response) => console.log(response.data))` it is returning me the whole html code of welcome.blade file on console.

Comment: what is your route for controller ?

Comment: yeah a url with a hashbang doen't look right for an ajax call

Comment: I removed the hashbang from the url and it's working now. Thanks everyone.